# How to insert data in excel worksheet in a position depending on another cell value with ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, closedxml

I have a treeView that I need to export to an excel file. I need to have the following output :

[image]

After failing to loop my treeView to export it from my code (I've tried several examples with no luck), I decided to get my data from my database on a list and tried to write each cell depending on a column called level (0, 1, 2, ...)

```
            var workSheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("data"); //creates the worksheet with sheetname 'data'
            workSheet.FirstRow().FirstCell().InsertData(_listGrpItems);
            workSheet.Column(1).Hide();
            workSheet.Column(3).Hide();
            workSheet.Column(4).Hide();
            workSheet.Column(5).Hide();
            workSheet.Column(6).Hide();

            foreach (IXLRow row in workSheet.Rows())
            {
                foreach (IXLCell cell in row.Cells())
                {
                    var level = row.Cell(4).Value;
                    cell.InsertCellsAfter(Convert.ToInt16(level));
                }
            }

            workbook.SaveAs(@"E:\data.xlsx");
```

The problem with this code is that the foreach loop doesn't seem to work correctly. I get error in the line `cell.InsertCellsAfter(Convert.ToInt16(level));` : `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException : 'Number of columns to insert must be a positive number no more than 16384
Nom du paramètre : numberOfColumns'`

Comment: What is the value of level when the exception is thrown?

Comment: The value of level is 0 that's why the exception is thrown. I added 1 to each level value.But, I ended up by chaging the method and copying the content of my treeview to clipboard and exporting it on a excel file. If you want me to post my solution please mention it.